# boost async_receive receiving unexpected random things

Tags: c++, boost-asio

i'm working on an irc server but the problem it's receiving something like this:
`CAP LS`
`NICK Fallen`
`USER Fallen 0 * :Fallen`
where it should be:

```
NICK Fallen
USER Fallen 0 * :Fallen
```

my code: http://pastebin.com/Li3wbpvu (i'm sorry i suck at posting code here it gets messy) 
EDIT: more details: and it's not even receiving every message in a new line.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's perfectly valid IRC protocol capabilities negotiation.

See some [references](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-baudis-irc-capab-00)